# Changing the search bar text in Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to change the default text in the search bar ("Search for records"):

[image: Search bar says "Search for records"]

Is this somehow possible? I've tried looking through the web interface, the JS files and the SQL database, but couldn't find where CRM stores this data.

Comment: It is called a watermark. There is an example of how to modify this in CRM 4.0 - not sure if this is any use to you - http://danielcai.blogspot.ie/2010/04/mscrm-40-watermark-crm-datetime-field.html

Comment: I think there is no supported way to do this, but it is possible if you use JQuery to change the watermark.

Comment: @Khoait is there a way to deploy a global JS script in CRM?

Comment: You can create and publish your JS to CRM but use have to add it to Library List of any Forms where you want to use it.